# Different appliances for a kitchen in stainless

Tags: kitchens, appliances

I am redoing my kitchen and looking for the best reviews of the various appliances. If I get them all in stainless, but from different manufacturers, will they match? Or do different companies have different stainless finishes that could clash?

Answer (score 1):

Different companies and even lines within companies use various grades and finishes of stainless. There aren't so many that you can't get pretty good matches. A lot of appliances these days are white label and will actually be the same unit with different bezels. That is particularly true with front-load washers but is seen across the appliance industry.